# How to use Mozilla Firefox features in IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

I have a problem in IE8 which does not support the features of Spagobi 4.0 server but in mozilla firefox it was working good.

But we can't use that Firefox software in Our domain.

so shall i have the firefox features in IE8 like add-ons...

kindly guide me..

thanks and regards,

Robert.J

Answer (score 0):

No add-ons can magically bring the rendering of Firefox to IE 8.

Apparently Spagobi 4.0 server [hasn't even been released yet, there just exists a release candidate](http://forge.ow2.org/project/showfiles.php?group_id=204). There doesn't exist documentation about it either, yet. I'd revert to stable version or submit a bug / wait for final release.